# How to set user-based .psql_history in linux?

Tags: postgresql, linux, psql

If use postgres in linux, it has a `postgres` user. So when use `psql` from this user, it will generate a `.psql_history` file under this user - /home/postgres/.psql_history.

When set many users on the linux server, all of them want to use the `psql` under their session like `/home/user1`. How to make them use `psql` and generate the psql history to each of them?

Like these

- /home/user1/.psql_history
- /home/user2/.psql_history
- /home/.../.psql_history

Is it necessary to install postgres client for each user?

Comment: If `user1` is a Unix user, why are not running `psql` and connecting to the database as that user? When `user1` logs, what does he type to connect to the database, something isn't making sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create unix user accounts for each person, and set user-name maps in pg_ident  so that everyone connects as postgres.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auth-username-maps.html

or alternatively create individual database users for each account and give them superuser privs. Optionally  "set session authenticaton postgres" can be set as a startup action in ~/.psqlrc if you want new relations to be owned by postgres - not that it makes much difference if everyone is already superuser.

Comment: He already has unix user accounts. He has `/home/user2/` I think we need to know how that user is connecting to the database to make sense of this.

Comment: he says "su postgres" (or similar)  then "psql"

Answer (score 2):

## Not an Ideal Configuration

PostgreSQL was created such that the permissions internal to the database are intended to mirror the system directly. You can get around that and it won't be too painful, but you're supposed to run `psql` as `user1` and `user2` per your example.

**Now what you're asking to do is an especially bad idea. `postgres` isn't a regular user, it's a Super User. These users can `DROP DB` and `TRUNCATE` at will. You probably don't want that account to be shared.**

But let's say that you do **NOT** want to grant each user the ability to connect to the database, or to create new databases. This isn't ideal but if you want to do that there are some mechanisms that may assists you, though subject to the caveat above, I would not share access to the `postgres` user ever.

### Environmental Variables

Use `HISTFILE` or `PSQL_HISTORY` or the environmental variable,

> **HISTFILE**
>
> The file name that will be used to store the history list. If unset, the file name is taken from the `PSQL_HISTORY` environment variable. If that is not set either, the default is `~/.psql_history`, or `%APPDATA%\postgresql\psql_history` on Windows. For example, putting:
>
> ```
> \set HISTFILE ~/.psql_history- :DBNAME
> ```
>
> in `~/.psqlrc` will cause psql to maintain a separate history for each database.
>
> Note: This feature was shamelessly plagiarized from Bash.

You can do this like

```
postgres$ SQL_HISTORY="/home/otheruser/.psql" psql
```

### Using sudo

You can also do `sudo -E` (`-E` is `--preserve-env`) observe,

```sh
❯ sudo -u postgres -- /bin/sh -c "echo ~/.psql_history"
/var/lib/postgresql/.psql_history
❯ sudo -E -u postgres -- /bin/sh -c "echo ~/.psql_history"
/home/ecarroll/.psql_history
```

You can see above with the `-E` flag we get the directory of the user that invokes `sudo` not the user that you're changing to. So you could log in as `postgres` and log history to your home directory by doing this,

```sh
❯ sudo -E -u postgres -- psql
```

Now you just have to decide who you want to give this very dangerous access to!